# alphabetical sort of letters in a string C

Tags: c, sorting, alphabetical

I am new to C programming and trying to write a program to sort a string of letters input by a user in to alphabetical order. So far I have the following code. Can anyone help me to get it to run properly? The code compiles and runs, but does not seem to store a running count correctly.

As far as debugging it I noticed the use of letter as a counter could be an issue, but have seen this done elsewhere and their [code](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-program-sort-string) compiles and runs fine. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        char str[10], strout[10] ;
        char letter ;
        int letter_count[26] = {0} ;
        int i, j , k, l, strlength ;

        printf("Please enter a string and I'll sort it \n") ;
        fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin) ;
        strlength = strlen(str) ;

        for(i = 0 ; i < strlength ; i++)
        {
                if((str[i] >= 'A') && (str[i] <= 'Z'))
                {
                        printf("Capital letter\n") ;
                        letter  = str[i] - 'A' ;
                        letter_count[letter] = letter_count[l] + 1  ;
                        printf("Letter %c has a count of %d\n",str[i], letter_count[i]) ;
                }
                else if((str[i] >= 'a') && (str[i] <= 'z'))
                {
                        printf("Lower case\n") ;
                        letter = str[i] - 'a' ;
                        letter_count[letter] = letter_count[l] + 1 ;
                        printf("Letter %c has a count of %d\n",str[i], letter_count[i]) ;
                }
        }

        k = 0 ;
        for( letter = 'a' ; letter <= 'z' ; letter++)
        {
                i = letter - 'a' ;
                for(j = 0 ; j <= letter_count[i] ; j++)
                {
                        strout[k] = letter ;
                        k++ ;
                }


        }
        return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several bugs in your code:

1. The following line which appears twice in the `for` loop is incorrect:

   ```
   letter_count[letter] = letter_count[l] + 1  ;
   ```

   The variable `l` is never initialized.
   Correct would be, for example:

   ```
   letter_count[letter]++;
   ```
2. The following is also wrong:

   ```
   printf("Letter %c has a count of %d\n",str[i], letter_count[i]) ;
   ```

   The count of the letter is in `letter_count[letter]` and not in `letter_count[i]`.
3. There is a [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) in the loop terminating condition:

   ```
   for(j = 0 ; j <= letter_count[i] ; j++)
   ```

   It should be changed to `j < letter_count[i]` otherwise you count each letter one time more than needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help